# Authentication in with B2C in android 11 fails with BAD request

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

Context:

We have MS team's personal tab application. We are using B2C authentication policy to sign in the user. Teams SDK has a method to open a popup with authentication flow which is being used in our application. This flow works fine in android 8 and 8.1 but gives an error in android 11 as viewed in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Has anyone observed the same with android 11? Any resolutions?

Comment: Could you please share the error logs which you are getting in android 11.
Also, could you please share the Teams client version that you are using?

Comment: Could you please share any sample you are referring to?

Comment: Apologies for responding lately. Actually, my android 11 phone is under warranty so I can not on the developer mode and check for the logs. And it works fine with other android devices.
@Meghana-MSFT we are referring the standard custom policy flow for b2c authentication using @azure/msal-angular, @azure/msal-browser

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft please find the request/response log for this issue at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wvoMc5sWaLJyJ4DVdQaLo4mmLbMStAp2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you confirm if you are seeing this issue on iOS also or only on Android 11?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT its only in case of Android 11. For android 8 also it works fine

Comment: I can see this only in android 11, not even in android 8

Comment: Could you please copy the URL in the above screenshot and open it in browser? That could give you more details related to the error.

Comment: Sorry, @ChetanSharma-msft. yes, I got it resolved.